# Add Qt 5.7 libraries to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ppa, qt5

I would like to add Qt 5.7 libraries to my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, to run a program that is precompiled (and needs Qt libraries 5.5 or later).  My system is text mode only (no runlevel 5) so I can't use the Qt creator packages.

Is there a PPA I can add to make the Qt 5.7 libraries available to me on Ubuntu 14.04?